# jQuery scrolling fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want the left div to scroll with the content, but the problem is that this div is higher then the screen. If the user is on the bottom of the page, they must see the bottom of the left div.

I'm using jQuery as js library

[image]

Comment: so... what exactly do you want?

Comment: how do you want the div to behave if it is bigger than the user's screen ?

Comment: my problem is, if I am on the bottom of page, i see on the left side white space, so i wont the left part is every time on the right height. If i css:fixed it, i see only the top of left content.

Comment: Could you please post the code you already have and maybe make a http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

use position:absolute instead of fixed.  Otherwise you can't really scroll a fixed div... kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: my problem is, if I am on the bottom of page, i see on the left side white space, so i wont the left part is every time on the right height. If i css:fixed it, i see only the top of left content.