# Scrollable-fixed div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a quiz application and I am currently doing the test page. 
I am planning to display all the questions on a single page and display question numbers in a table on the left side so that candidates can use to navigate to the questions.

But I want that table to be visible always. I mean I want it as a fixed element. But unfortunately when the number of questions is high, the table overflows out of the view and I am not able to see the bottom parts.

Is there anyway to make that div fixed as well as provide a scroll bar for the contents of that div?

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

I am using "affix" class of bootstrap to do the div fixing. 
Here's is the mark up:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
  <table class="table table-condensed bs-docs-sidenav affix">
  <caption><strong>Questions Navigation</strong></caption>
      <% @q_array.each do |row|%>
        <tr>
          <% row.each do |qn| %>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><%= link_to qn,"#",:class=>"btn btn-inverse"%></td>
          <%end%>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="span9">

<%= @questions.keys[0] %>
<%= @questions.values[0][1] %>
<%=@questions %>
<%=@q_array%>

</div>
</div>
```

`.bs-docs-sidenav` is a css class I took from bootstrap docs pages. It sets width and border rouding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try **overflow-y:auto;** and **overflow-x:hidden;** in the **affix** css class

Comment: Set a height to your div and the property overflow:scroll. also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900226/jquery-scrolling-fixed-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `height` to your `div` and the property `overflow:scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

try putting overflow to your `affix css class`

```
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
```